# Overflowed height - jQuery

Tags: jquery

[image]

How can i get the height of overflowed part in my document.

Example: I resized the window and scrollbar appear, how can i obtain the height of the part that is out of the window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code; have you tried anything?

Comment: Subtract from document's height the viewport size? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic equation here is

```
documentHeight == windowHeight + scrollTop + scrollBottom

~

scrollBottom == documentHeight - windowHeight - scrollTop
```

With basic javascript (works with IE7 and above):

```js
var winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var docH = document.body.clientHeight;
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
var scrollBottom = docH - winH - scrollTop;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTHuL/

http://jsfiddle.net/QTHuL/show  (fullscreen, can be tested in old browsers)

In jQuery it's even simpler:

```
var winH = $(window).height();
var docH = $(document).height();
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var scrollBottom = docH - winH - scrollTop;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTHuL/1/

Answer (score 6):

The height of the document (all content) less the height of the viewport.

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height()
```